# Why can I declare @objc protocols as weak properties, but not swift protocols?

Tags: swift, protocols, weak-references

I found out that if I created a protocol like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }
```

I can't do this:

```
weak var myVar: MyProtocol?
```

And I found the way to fix this, which is adding `@objc` to the protocol declaration:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol { }
```

But why can this fix the error?

My guess is that adding `@objc` prevents structs to conform to the protocol, so the value of the variable is gurranteed to be a reference type. Am I right?

Also, adding `@objc` prevents me from adding swift types like `[String: Any]`. I also would like to know is there another way of fixing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weak references can only be created for *reference types*, i.e. instances
of a class, not for value types (struct or enums).

If you declare the protocol as a "class-only protocol"

```
protocol MyProtocol : class { }
```

then you can declare a weak variable of that type:

```
weak var myVar: MyProtocol?
```

In your case

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol { }
```

declares a protocol which can only be adopted by `NSObject` subclasses
or other `@objc` classes, so that is implicitly a class-only protocol.

Comment: So my guess is right! I never knew that @objc protocols can only be adopted by NSObject subclasses! Thanks!

Comment: @Sweeper: Strictly speaking, it can be adopted by NSObject subclasses or other `@objc` classes, but don't ask me for the precise difference now :)